# Query Embedded Document List in MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoengine

I need query a list with all embedded documents in mongoengine. Here is my schema:

```
class Variant(EmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField(required=True)
    value = StringField(required=True)

class Sku(Document):
    variants = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Variant))
```

I can do it using mongo shell with:

```
db.sku.find({variants: [{'name': 'xxx', 'value': 'xxx'}]}).pretty()
```

But I haven't figure out a way to do it in mongoengine. I need the list in the document is exactly the same with the list I put in the query. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually you were doing it "incorrectly" in the shell as well. The format you were using requires an **exact match** that would "rarely" actually match conditions. It certainly would not should the inner keys of the array be stored in a different order, **or** most importantly that the array itself actually stored more than one element.

The correct form for the "shell" would be:

```js
db.sku.find({ "variants": { "$elemMatch": { "name": "xxx", "value": "xxx" } } })
```

By the same token, the "correct" form for MongoEngine is:

```js
Sku.objects(variants__match={ "name": "xxx", "value": "xxx" })
```

The [`__match`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#string-queries) construct here is the same thing as, and actually issues an [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) statement in query to the underlying MongoDB database as a query.

Note that for a "single" element condition the general "double underscore" syntax is just fine:

```js
Sku.objects(variants__name="xxx")
```

But for "multiple" conditions and/or elements within the array/list, you need [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) as a MongoDB query and therefore [`__match`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#string-queries).

Comment: What if I need two elements in the array? Like:
db.sku.find({variants: [{'name': 'xxx', 'value': 'xxx'},{'name': 'yyy', 'value': 'yyy'} ]}).pretty()

Comment: @JoeyHu That is a different question to what you asked, and this answers only the question you "actually asked". If you have a new question then [Ask a new Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead. That's how we do it here, as one question and one definitive answer. [This question you asked is answered](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/